# Use integration by parts to show Riemann–Lebesgue lemma

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, riemann-integration

If $f'$ is continuous in [a,b] use integration by parts to show Riemann–Lebesgue lemma:

$$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty}\int_a^b f(x)\sin(\lambda x) \, dx =0$$

I did the following  $$\int_a^b f(x) \sin(\lambda x) \, dx = -f(x)\frac{\cos(\lambda x)}{\lambda} + \int_a^b \frac{\cos(\lambda x)}{\lambda}  f'(x) \, dx$$

If then I insert limit on both sides I don't know what to do next

Comment: What is $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty} C/\lambda$ when $C$ is a constant?

Comment: But what guarantees that f (x) is not zero or infinity?

Comment: You also missed in doing integration by parts, you need to actually put those definite limits on the first part

Comment: You're right, I forgot

Answer (score 1):

Since $f'$ is continuous on a closed and bounded domain $[a,b]$ it is bounded. Since $f$ is differentiable and therefore also continuous, the same conclusion can be drawn. Similarly for $\cos(\lambda x)$. Therefore as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$ both terms in your sum tend to zero.

Comment: But how can I guarantee it is bounded? Is there a theorem?
I think about the extreme value theorem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It hasn't really got a name, just a well known result. If it weren't true that $f$ was bounded we could take a sequence of points $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(x_n)>n$. Since [a,b] is compact  ( or equivlantly by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem) this sequence has a convergent subsequence converging to some $x \in [a,b]$ , but this means $f(x)=\infty$ a contradiction.